# hi, i want to traverse numpy array to show only 100 images out of 2656

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

this is my array shape
print (img_array.shape)
(2656, 256, 256, 3)

and this is how I am printing single image

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img3 = img_array[2655,:,:,:]
cv2_imshow(img3)
```

i want to print 100
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first 100 images

```
img3 = img_array[0:99]
```

but it is producing error
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 256, 3), |u1

Comment: You don't share the code where you are getting images like this
images = glob(os.path.join(SOURCE_IMAGES, "*.png"))
and then the above line will work 
img3 = images[0:99]

Comment: For your reference
https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/resize-and-save-images-as-numpy-arrays-128x128